# uncaught referenceerror: Highcharts is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm facing this error "uncaught referenceerror: Highcharts is not defined"
Can you please help

I have added the below code

```
<script src="../../webRoot/webResource/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../webRoot/webResource/js/highcharts.js"></script>
```

also please find my HighCharts related code:

> ```
> $(function () {
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         var options = new Object();
>         options.chart = new Object();
>         options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
>         options.chart.type = 'line';
>         options.series = new Array();
>         for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
>             options.series[i] = new Object();
>             options.series[i].name = 'china';
>             options.series[i].data = new Array(i, i + 1, i + 2);
>         }
>         var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
>     });
> });
> ```

I'm getting that error at:

> var chart=new HighCharts.Chart(options)

Comment: Why do you have a document.ready in a document.ready?

Comment: Your reference to the `highcharts.js` file is relative to the page. So the path to find it should be two folders up from where *this script/page* is hosted and then inside the `webRoot/webResources/` folders. If this page is, say, three levels deep inside a folder, it would be able to find the `highcharts.js` file. Change this to an absolute reference or verify/change the src and it should work.